# Open File Selection dojox/Uploader programmatically

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dojo

I need to select a file to upload with dojox/Uploader by clicking on a `div` not related to the widget.

I've tried using `on.emit`, but nothing happens (also `click()`, `onclick()` etc... on domNodes..)

This is my code:

```
var myUploader = new dojox.form.Uploader({
            id : 'myUploader',
            url : baseUrl + '/upload/form',
            style : {
                'overflow': 'hidden',
                'position': 'relative',
                'opacity' : 0                   
            }
        },"uploaderHolder");

myUploader.startup();

var importButtonNode = dom.byId("importDivButton");

on(importButtonNode,"click",function(evt) {
    on.emit(myUploader.domNode, "click", {
         bubbles: true,
        cancelable: false
});
```

The widget must be hidden, so I can't press widget select button. I need open select file dialog by click other div so... how can I open the file browser programmatically to select a file?

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: how can i open the file browser programatically to select a file? The widget button will be hidden.

Comment: Please add your question to the question article by clicking on `edit` and modify accordingly. This helps finding answers to your question.

Comment: Done, the question has been added

Comment: Thanks for your comments Gottieb Notschnabel!

Comment: You're very welcome. [Here is some more information about how to ask on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I find out a solution. I take a widgets inner node to call click, and attach a listener to the Uploader change event and complete event...

First, attach click event to a node.

```
var importButtonNode = dom.byId("myImportDiv");
on(importButtonNode,"click",function(evt) {
    myUploader.domNode.childNodes[0].click();
});
```

Attach to Uploader change and complete events a handler

```
myUploader.on("change",function(evt){
    if(evt[0].type != FileTypes.XSLX_FILE_TYPE){
        alert("Error file type must be XLSX");              
    } else {
        var formData = new Object();
        formData.idProject =  project.id;
        myUploader.upload(formData);    
    }
});
myUploader.on("complete",function(evt){
    alert("File Uploaded");
    // do things

});
```

In my case I need send formdata without a form... so use de upload method. Also the file must be XLSX.

I hope this helps.

Regards